# Why the width and height of the image are halved to calculate the inSampleSize of image?

Tags: android, bitmap

The code below was taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) at the Android Developers website.

In the code the `calculateInSampleSize` method is used to calculate the `inSampleSize` of the image to scale down the image and sub sample it.

I just want to know the reason of division by two in the final int `height` and `width`

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps  
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }   
    return inSampleSize;
}
```